# MFMailComposeViewController mail reciepient limit

Tags: ios, gmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating an ios application,in which I have to more than 1000 mails from the device.I am using the MFMailComposeViewController.
**My doubt is** Is there any limit for the recipient number?
Is that possible to send more than 1000 mail from the device? Or whether we have to send it from the server?

If anybody has idea,then please give me a solution
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) there´s no limit defined for the number of recipients.

You just give an Array of NSString objects to

```
- (void)setToRecipients:(NSArray*)toRecipients
```

But maybe your server should handle this mass-email procedure. Maybe the devices don´t carry the systemressources this needs with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.SO you are telling that ,if we are sending bulk mails from the device then it will effect the performance(may crash or hang) .So we can use server for sending bulk mail.am I ryt?

Comment: I have not tested sending so many mails, but it might be too much for the device.